# Large sizes in iOS Universal apps due to a million images

Tags: ios, ipad, splash-screen, ios-universal-app

Ok, I have a universal app, which means it has to have an iPhone non-retina launch image, retina image, and iPhone 5+ size retina image.  It also has to have non-retina iPad launch for portrait and landscape, retina for portrait and landscape, and then alternate versions as well with slight changes to dimensions.  For example, on iPad I have to have a 768 x 1024 and a 768 x 1004.  With 8 images required just for the iPad launch image, the file size of my app is huge, as each iPad launch image is between 1.5MB and 5MB.  Any suggestions for how I can keep the size down, since it is only high due to large launch images?

Here is what I mean by all the images required for iPad.  8 images???

[image]

Comment: What is the million images in the question about? And in addition the image requirement for universal iPad iPhone app is the same as you already know. There is no way around it. Unless you use one image and resize it manually. That maybe done although I never had the need to do it.

Comment: XCodeMonkey see the picture in my edit

Comment: i understand your dilema. trust me i am in it. i haven't seen a work around anywhere yet, and have not received a satisfactory answer from apple. i hate it as much as you do but it seems there is no way out of this for now.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to reduce the size greatly is provide jpeg images instead of png. Yeah, I know, Apple asks for png, but you can submit an app with jpg images (I did this for my iPad app).

Use Preview to open the images. save them as JPEGs with a really low quality - or experiment with the quality setting. You will be amazed at how nice a really compressed JPG image can look.

Oh, your launch time might increase by a few milliseconds due to Apple translating the jpg to png during launch.

My experience was submitting when iOS5 was out, so its possible that not using PNG will be a blocker with iOS7. However, I even have a solution if that is needed. Do as I suggest - save the images as highly compressed jpg images first. Then convert THOSE images to pngs - the jpg compression done first should make it easier for png to compress the those images, reducing the size.

There are several PNG "crushers" - programs to reduce PNG size - that work great. Just make sure that you unselect the option to have Xcode "reduce the PNG sizes" - since it actually increases their size!

Comment: Adding JPEG format images or jpg will result in rejection of your app as far as launch images is concern. Just saying.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey, and you know this as a fact? I do know as a fact I could do this when iOS5 was the latest. Just curious to know that your app was rejected. Its easy enough to test - just try the next time, if you make it fine, if not, well try suggestion 2, which is to get your image to be so reduced in changes as to compress well with PNG compression (lossless).

Comment: Since I tried twice with iOS 6 and my app was rejected and then I changed it to png and passed, yes I know that for a fact. But I will promise to try it in my new iOS 7 app next week when I upload it, and since I respect you as a experienced coder with a high reputation, I will post the results for you. After all you may be right my friend, and I  am now and always will be a good student.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey, hah, note that I used rather old experience - iOS5.  I set the launch images only as jpg, since as everyone knows png is usually so much larger. BUT, if you can reduce the complexity of the images - png can better compress them. PNG is lossless - it will not remove one bit from the final image. that said, the idea is to feed it an image that has little variation - so it can better compress it. the easiest way I know to do this is to start with a highly compressed jpg image! So please, I am not doubting you were rejected!